# Nitya Granth by Ramanujacarya

Tags: rituals

Does anyone know if there is an English translation of Nitya Granth by Ramanujacarya? Any links to the book or to purchase it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Click (https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/kriya-deepah-and-nithya-granthah-2-books-in-one-binding-nam693/)!
This is an translation of K.R.Krishnaswami a Sri Vaishnava Acharya.

Comment: @Payuh Vaisnava Thanks